How do I add a hyperlink in one HTML file to another HTML file?
I have a Documents folder, which is of the Document Library type. Inside, I have a temp folder that includes two HTML files: a.html and b.html. In the a.html file, there's a link to the b.html file (B file). When I open the a.html file using an HTML viewer and click on the B file hyperlink, I receive a "404 NOT FOUND" notification. I also tried using the absolute path without success. I know that I can use Pages in the Page library, but this solution doesn't help me enough. I want to use SharePoint as the place where I will add my HTML reports, minimizing the effort required.
